# Variables is nil in awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, awakefromnib

I created a custom UIView that I instantiate with an object ConnectDetailItem.

Code of my custom view :

```
class InfosConnectView: UIView {

    var view: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var categorie: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var followers: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!

    var connectDetailsItem:ConnectDetailsItem!

    convenience init(connectDetailsItem:ConnectDetailsItem, frame:CGRect) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.connectDetailsItem = connectDetailsItem
        xibSetup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        view.frame = bounds

        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]

        view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hex: "#DDDDDD").cgColor

        // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "viewInfosConnect", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        //Infos Connect
        self.categorie.text = "\(self.connectDetailsItem.category)"
        self.categorie.text = "\(self.connectDetailsItem.category)"
        if (self.connectDetailsItem.distance < 1000) {
            self.distance.text = "\(self.connectDetailsItem.distance) m"
        } else {
            let distance:NSString = NSString(format: "%.01f", Float(self.connectDetailsItem.distance)/1000)
            self.distance.text = "\(distance) km"
        }
        if(self.connectDetailsItem.followCount < 2) {
            if(self.connectDetailsItem.followCount < 1) {
                self.followers.text = "0 abonné"
            } else {
                self.followers.text = "\(self.connectDetailsItem.followCount) abonné"
            }
        } else {
            self.followers.text = "\(self.connectDetailsItem.followCount) abonnés"
        }
        self.descriptionTextView.text = self.connectDetailsItem.description
    }

}
```

In `awakeFromNib()`, `connectDetailItem` is `nil`. Why ?

I instanciate my view like this : `let viewInfos = InfosConnectView(connectDetailsItem: self.connectDetailsItem, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 9, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200))`

I set breakpoints and before entering the awakeFromNib function connectDetailItem is not nil.

Comment: Check view address. Maybe it is different view exemplars?

Comment: If I comment all lines in awakeFromNib(), view displays correctly.

Comment: You told that problem is not in "correctly" displaying. "connectDetailsItem" is nil anyway. Please check view addresses in memory. You can do it in debugger. It looks like: "0x12345678"

Comment: Try putting all your code from your `awakeFromNib` and put it inside a function. And call that function from both `init` and `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Where call this function Rikh ?

Comment: Nikita, connectDetailsItem is not nil when instanciate custom view, but from awakeFromNib(), connectDetailsItem is nil.

Comment: You're not loading the outer view from a nib or a storyboard, so `awakeFromNib` is not called. When you're loading such view from a nib or a storyboard, your convenience constructor is not called.

Comment: I load it from a nib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.
I put the code in the function loadViewFromNib like this :

```
func loadViewFromNib() -> InfosConnectView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "viewInfosConnect", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! InfosConnectView

        //Infos Connect
        view.categorie.text = "\(self.connectDetailsItem.category)"
        if (self.connectDetailsItem.distance < 1000) {
            view.distance.text = "\(self.connectDetailsItem.distance) m"
        } else {
            let distance:NSString = NSString(format: "%.01f", Float(self.connectDetailsItem.distance)/1000)
            view.distance.text = "\(distance) km"
        }
        if(self.connectDetailsItem.followCount < 2) {
            if(self.connectDetailsItem.followCount < 1) {
                view.followers.text = "0 abonné"
            } else {
                view.followers.text = "\(self.connectDetailsItem.followCount) abonné"
            }
        } else {
            view.followers.text = "\(self.connectDetailsItem.followCount) abonnés"
        }
        view.descriptionTextView.text = self.connectDetailsItem.description

        return view
    }
```